# how to put data from List<Object> to String array Android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, object, android-arrayadapter

This is the object i want to insert into the array. The getters ans setters are all defined.

```
public class Task {

private int id;
private String title;
private String description;

public Task(){}

public Task(String title, String description) {
    super();
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
}

//getters & setters
}
```

Here is the getAllTasks method which is converting the data in my database to Task objects and then making the objects to a List.

```
public List<Task> getAllTasks() {
    List<Task> tasks = new LinkedList<Task>();

    // 1. build the query
    String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TASKS;

    // 2. get reference to writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    // 3. go over each row, build task and add it to list
    Task task = null;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            task = new Task();
            task.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            task.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
            task.setDescription(cursor.getString(2));

            // Add task to tasks
            tasks.add(task);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    Log.d("getAllTasks()", tasks.toString());

    // return tasks
    return tasks;
}
```

This is what i want to perform:

I want to insert the objects in the String array taskList.

```
MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
    List<Task> tasks = db.getAllTasks();
    String [] taskList = new String[tasks.size()];
    int index = 0;
    for (Task value : tasks) {
        taskList[index] = String.valueOf( value );
        index++;
    }
```

Comment: Do you strictly need a String array? It seems as though your data would suggest you need the two Strings independently, is this a bad assumption? If you do need them independently, you may want to consider an array of String arrays, or a List of String arrays.

Comment: I dont understand the exact purpose of your code. But you would have to override the `toString` method in youc class to get a meaningful string representation of your object.

But that array of Strings would be of no use to you except for printing it.

If you could explain what your purpose is, then maybe we can help you

Comment: I am trying to use the string array taskList in an arrayAdapter to output it on a ListView

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the Object `toString` method for the class `Task`.

Example:

```
public String toString() {
    return "Task [id=" + id + ", title=" + title + ", description=" + description + "]";
}
```